# Promise in requestInterceptor of Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui

Is it possible to return promise object from requestInterceptor, will swagger client wait for the promise returned to resolve before invoking actual http call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supported in [Swagger UI 3.13.3+](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases/tag/v3.13.3). From the [documentaton](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#network) (emphasis mine):

> `requestInterceptor`
>
> `Function=(a => a)`. MUST be a function. Function to intercept remote definition, Try-It-Out, and OAuth2 requests. Accepts one argument requestInterceptor(request) and must return the modified request, **or a Promise that resolves to the modified request**.